# PeriodicTimer with dynamic period in a BackgroundService

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, background-service, .net-7.0, periodictimer

I'm using

```
using PeriodicTimer timer = new(_period);

while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested
    && await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
{
    await DoWork();
}
```

Is there a way to set `_period` dynamically? that is, take that period of a database for example.

Comment: You mean change the period on instantiated timer?

Comment: yes, or some way to set the time from BBDD while the service is running. Should I do it inside the while?

Comment: I made a contrived working example of your code, https://dotnetfiddle.net/wnKhAJ

Comment: As a side note, checking the `stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested` before awaiting the `timer` results in inconsistent cancellation behavior. The loop might complete either successfully or as canceled, depending on the (non-deterministic) timing of the cancellation. My suggestion is to remove the check, to make the behavior consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A new property [`PeriodicTimer.Period`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer.period) has been introduced on .NET 8:

> Gets or sets the period between ticks.

Originally this answer contained a custom `UpdateablePeriodicTimer` implementation, featuring the (then lacking) `Period` property. In case you are targeting .NET 6 or 7, you can find it in the [1st revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75273471/1) of this answer. I am no longer satisfied with that implementation though, because when I wrote it I was not aware of a [by design](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/95238#issuecomment-1826758659) behavior of the `PeriodicTimer` class:

> This is by design. The timer starts when the instance is created, not when you call `WaitForNextTickAsync`. If the timer ticks before the call, it'll complete immediately. That's true even when it's not the first, eg if you call Wait and it completes, then you go away for longer than the period, the next call to Wait will also likely complete immediately.

Answer (score 3):

No, a [`Periodic Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-threading-periodictimer-ctor(system-timespan)) does not allow `period` to be changed after instantiation.

You can construct the original or a new different `Periodic Timer` with a value you got from elsewhere but, be sure the `Dispose` instances so that the required resources can be released.

If you need a variable delay, your could use [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-7.0) instead.

Comment: using using as in my question doesn't release resources? or do I have to call dispose when I finish my job?

Comment: @Angelru, your use of `using` is correct and will guarantee that `Dispose` is called correctly.

Comment: @Angelru `using` is readonly. You will need to expand it into try-finally manually and additionally call `Dispose` in the loop when recreating the timer.

Comment: but when I use using, dispose is not called automatically?